# Powershell pipeline with where not behaving as expected

Tags: powershell

When I use where filter to exclude an object with pipeline command it is not giving me the correct output.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $proall = Get-ADComputer -filter * | ? {$_.name -ne "adfs"} | select @{l='Computername';e={$_
.name}} | ps | select machinename,processname,id | sort id | ft -au

MachineName ProcessName                             Id
----------- -----------                             --
DC          Idle                                     0
DC          Idle                                     0
DC          Idle                                     0
DC          System                                   4
DC          System                                   4
DC          System                                   4
DC          mmc                                     96
DC          mmc                                     96
DC          mmc                                     96
DC          smss                                   276
DC          smss                                   276
DC          smss                                   276
DC          svchost                                304
DC          svchost                                304
DC          svchost                                304
```

So here the no. of processes we see are more than the actual no. of processes on the machine. However there are no specific processes(exchange and sharepoint) from other machine.

---

To check my command I have ensured the following output are as expected.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ADComputer -filter * | ? {$_.name -ne "adfs"} | select @{l='Computername';e={$_.name}}

Computername
------------
DC
SP2013
EX2013
```

AND

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | ? {$_.name -eq "sp2013"} | select @{l='Computername';e={$_.name}} | get-process

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
     96       9     1664      11264    94            2712 conhost
     94       9     1608      11004    95            5792 conhost
    326      15     1484       4032    56             392 csrss
```

I have ensured the above process are specific to the computer specified in the '?'/'Where' filter.

The problem is when I exclude a specific object.

I would like to know why it is behaving this way. I am not looking for result but trying to understand the syntax.

Regards

**EDIT: Added the output with ID. I see 3 instances of each process(Same ID); No. of computer output is also 3.**

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the number of processes are wrong? What happens when you run `Get-Process -ComputerName DC` manually?

Comment: You could change your final select to `select machinename,processname,id`. That way you will see all the process ids to know if there is any repetiion

Comment: "Get-Process -ComputerName DC"  returns 45 processes. Whereas "Get-ADComputer -filter * | ? {$_.name -ne "adfs"} | select @{l='Computername';e={$_.name}} |
ps | select machinename,processname | sort processname | ft -au" returns  139 processes

Comment: That sure looks like it's outputting the `ps` for the DC server 3 times, so once for each server instead of each server's results. Can you pipe the `ps` directly into `| group MachineName` and see what it shows as results?

Comment: `Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
  135 DC                        {System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost),` This is what i see @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Then yeah, 135 is 45*3, so it's just outputting the DC server 3 times for whatever reason. What version of PowerShell is this? You'd think they'd have a bug like that patched by now.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I can see the same behavior on PowerShell 4.0......

Comment: Still investingating. Must have something to do with binding since this makes the issue go away `ForEach-Object { ps -ComputerName $_.Computername}`

Comment: If I am reading a trace correctly I see that each computer name is successfully bound to the pipe. Leads me to think `Get-Process` is at fault for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug..... Read below.

I have been testing with PowerShell 4.0 and see the same issue are you. I can make the problem go away if I do not allow the parameters to be bound by the pipeline.

```
Get-ADComputer -filter '*' | 
    ? {$_.name -ne "adfs"} | 
    select @{l='Computername';e={$_.name}} | 
    %{ ps -ComputerName $_.Computername} |
    select machinename,processname,id | sort id | ft -au
```

That made me think that parameter binding was at fault. So I used `trace-command` against what I feel is the offending code  `| ps`. `$computers` is just the result of the earlier code. I was testing with two hosts.

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression {$computers | ps} -PSHost
```

Unfortunately I didn't see anything other than the exact same entries for each unit. Only fact I think I can get out of that is that `ps` was getting each computer name.

Going to check and see if this was reported already.

---

**It's a bug**

You are not the first one to see this. I found a [preexisting report on this](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/1164861) which I voted up and acknowledged that I could reproduce. So it is the nature of the beast for now. If you want it to work you would need to use a workaround like I show above. I am impressed by your pipeline prowess. Too bad it did not work out this time.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think that answers my question. The syntax is right, it is not  behaving the way it should.

Comment: Awesome research and follow up man, I wish I could give more than one up-vote for this kind of effort for a free service. Plus I've never seen `Trace-Command` before, so that was fun to see :)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I am starting to enjoy these questions more that "why cant I filter on format-taco"

Comment: I agree with @TheMadTechnician, definitely deserves more than one up-vote. With people like Matt it is  lot easier for newbie like me to get started.  BTW if it helps anybody, While practicing I found same bug applied to get-service and get-process :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the problem is that `ps` accepts process objects on the pipeline, not computernames.

Try this:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * | ? {$_.name -ne "adfs"} | foreach-object{ ps -computername $_.name| select machinename,processname,id | sort id} |
```

Comment: I don't think that that's the problem, `select @{l='ComputerName';e={$_.Name}}` should have already taken care of that

Comment: Thanks Mike. I still don't understand why the command does not work when using where to exclude a specific computer and works when specifying a specific computer... I am still learning.

Comment: I see it now.  The "Input" section of the help on get-process doesn't mention it but the ComputerName parameter allows pipeline input by property name.

Comment: Thanks Mathias for your inputs